# Android- Take More Number Screen Shots to make as Video

Tags: android, bitmap, screenshot

I want to take more number of Screenshots (approx min 15/sec ), To make them as video,Since I could not Find any option to record my Screen as Video (to support all the device including non rooted), So this is one solution I am trying.

As of now I am using the below code take the Screenshots.

```
 View v1 = MyView.getRootView();
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

saveImagetoMyLocal();
```

I am calling the Above method in the Handler which running for each 100 milliseconds. But the Problem is its Affecting My UI responsiveness, In my UI i need play some animation, Which is actually affected because of the above process. Even I tried calling the above method in AsyncTask but, I am facing the same problem. Now i want answer for below scenario.

1) Do we have any code for recording the Screen as Video (Including non rooted device)

2) How I could solve the above problem ?

Comment: On the higher api levels, you can use adb/DDMS to record video screencasts (even on non-rooted devices). Would that be sufficient?

Comment: @Stephan, I need to record like a video within my app itself.  Sorry, I don't understand How i can use the DDMS or adb if my Device not connected via USB.

Comment: No need to apologize. I just didn't know if you needed to get this done as part of the app itself, or as part of some developer/testing tool you were making.